# Debug Information Shown as Part of Footer and Displaying Only One Line? Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails Tutorial Chapter 7

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, ruby

Hartl's RoR Tutorial introduces debug information and has it set up in such a way that it shows at the bottom of each page in a separate box container. Rather than display in a separate box, my rendering seems to put it with the footer and only show the first line of debug information.

My default browser is Chrome but I get the same rendering in Edge and Firefox as well.

[Debug information as currently shown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCvkY.jpg)

[Debug information as it should be displayed per Hartl's text](https://softcover.s3.amazonaws.com/636/ruby_on_rails_tutorial_3rd_edition/images/figures/home_page_with_debug_3rd_edition.png)

Here is a link to Hartl's text, the debug step I'm referencing is in Listing 7.2

www dot railstutorial dot org/book/sign_up

Here is the related code from my css file and my application layout.  If there is any other code you'd like for me to provide, please let me know and I'll update the posting.  Thank you for your help!

**assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss:**

```
/* Commonly used styling - mixins, variables, etc */

/* Listing 7.2 */
@mixin box_sizing {
  -moz-box-sizing:     border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing:  border-box;
  box-sizing:          border-box;
}

/* Footer */

footer {
  margin-top: 45px;
  padding-top: 5px;
  border-top: 1px solid $grey-medium-light;
  color: $grey-light;
  a {
    color: #555;
    &:hover {
      color: #222;
    }
  }
  small {
    float: left;
  }
  ul {
    float: right;
    list-style: none;
    li {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 15px;
    }
  }
}

/* Miscellaneous */

/* Listing 7.2 */
.debug_dump {
  clear: both;
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  // height: auto; 
  margin-top: 45px;
  @include box_sizing(border-box); // Modified to include argument
}
```

**app/views/layouts/application.html.erb, *see div class "container" at the bottom:***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <!-- Listing 3.32 -->
    <!-- Listing 4.3 -->
    <title><%= full_title(yield(:title)) %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>

    <!-- Listing 5.8. The point of this is to direct the program to a specific file (in this case, app/views/layouts/_shim.html.erb, evaluate the contents, and insert the results into the view.  Previously, the shim code was listed here, which kind of cluttered up the layout file's contents.  By branching individual pieces off to their own file, it can help make things cleaner and easier to maintain.-->
    <%= render 'layouts/shim' %>

  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- Listing 5.8, the previous header class content stuff that was listed here was moved into its own _header.html.erb file, found in app/views/layouts.  Rather than put the code here, it's now referenced with the below render layouts/header command.  Coolio!  Really makes things a lot easier to manage -->
    <%= render 'layouts/header' %>

    <div class="container">
      <%= yield %>

      <!-- Listing 5.12 Adding a reference the footer layout file -->
      <%= render 'layouts/footer' %>

      <!-- Listing 7.1 Adding debug parameters to the development environment only.  Because you don't want users on the production side to see any of this stuff -->
      <% debug(params) if Rails.env.development?
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add the closing %> plus = for the debug params!

To show the debug:

```
<%= debug(params) if Rails.env.development? %>
```

Comment: Beautiful, thank you for your sharp eyes TomD!  That did the trick